# GPU Overdraw (ionic / cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gpu-overdraw

Ive been reading into App optimisation and have come across the GPU overdraw functionality embedded in the Developer menu in Android.

There are some great articles here that I have read

http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/
http://www.curious-creature.com/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html

The issue here is within my Ionic App it does not show any overdraw. I am interested to see if I can make any optimisations or changes to my App and see how it performs.

Does anyone have any information on whether you can get overdraw to show, or if there is even a point in doing so?

Comment: If you are using Android 4.4 (KitKat) and above, you can use Chrome Remote Debugging on a WebView https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews. The GPU overdraw I believe is for native UI components.

Comment: Thanks Morrison, I am aware of the Chrome debugging tools, but it does make sense that GPU overdraw would only be for native components. Am using 5.1 on an LG G4